# What is the core difference between t=&T{} and t=new(T)

Tags: pointers, go, struct, new-operator

It seems that both ways to create a new object pointer with all "0" member values, both returns a pointer:

```
type T struct{}
...
t1:=&T{}
t2:=new(T)
```

So what is the core difference between t1 and t2, or is there anything that "new" can do while &T{} cannot, or vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> […] is there anything that "new" can do while &T{} cannot, or vice versa?

I can think of three differences:

- The "composite literal" syntax (the `T{}` part of `&T{}`) only works for "structs, arrays, slices, and maps" [[link](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)], whereas the `new` function works for any type [[link](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Allocation)].
- For a struct or array type, the `new` function always generates zero values for its elements, whereas the composite literal syntax lets you initialize some of the elements to non-zero values if you like.
- For a slice or map type, the `new` function always returns a pointer to `nil`, whereas the composite literal syntax always returns an initialized slice or map. (For maps this is very significant, because you can't add elements to `nil`.) Furthermore, the composite literal syntax can even create a *non*-empty slice or map.

(The second and third bullet-points are actually two aspects of the same thing — that the `new` function always creates zero values — but I list them separately because the implications are a bit different for the different types.)

Comment: Technically, a new slice or map *is* initialized (to all-zero-values). This technical point is particularly important when the elements of the map or slice are themselves pointers (but is guaranteed in general).

Comment: @torek: The language specification disagrees with you. (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals is really quite explicit.)

Comment: What does the fact that `new` initializes the value (to zero) have to do with composite literals? (Perhaps it wasn't clear that when I said "a new slice or map" I meant "a new slice or map created by `new`.) ... Ah, perhaps you're talking about how it says that a slice created by `new` is "uninitialized". The new slice has length zero and capacity zero. I'd argue that if the length and capacity are initialized, that means the slice *is* initialized. Internally, the `unsafe.Pointer` inside it is nil, which is also "initialized" in an important internal sense.

Comment: But on the other hand, `new` is very different from `make`, which sets all accessible values to zero as well.

Comment: Basically, all of this is only stuff you can discover by poking around with the `unsafe` package, so it's not an *observable* difference: the language doesn't really promise things one way or another. But to the internal gc code, it matters (for efficiency).

Comment: (Or, to put it another way, I think the comment in the section you pointed out, where it uses the word "uninitialized", is ... not exactly a bug, but rather a sort of bad phrasing, in the spec. But it's in a comment, so maybe it doesn't count. )

Comment: @torek: The spec consistently uses the word "uninitialized" this way -- see also https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types -- so while I see where you're coming from, I don't think it's wise to push a different understanding of that term. Also, even on your own terms, I think your comments are wrong when it comes to maps: you can add elements to an empty map, but not to `nil`, so `foo := new(map[string]int) ; (*foo)["bar"] = 6` panics while `foo := &map[string]int{} ; (*foo)["bar"] = 6`  does not.

Comment: @torek: FWIW, I've now edited my answer to use "`nil`" and contrast it with "initialized", rather than using the term "uninitialized", since you're probably not the only person to misunderstand the latter. I also added a note about why the distinction matters for maps.

Comment: I'll buy that, or at least most of it; I just think the use of the word "uninitialized" here is ... not great.  Setting a map or slice variable to nil really does initialize the internal header components, which is pretty important internally. The nil map is similar: there is a map header, which you can (but normally shouldn't) inspect using `unsafe` and parts of `reflect` that are not promised to stay the same in the future.

Comment: @torek: Well, keep in mind that if you don't literally initialize a map or slice variable, you get `nil`. The fact that even `nil` involves some "initialization"-like implementation details isn't really relevant from the spec's standpoint IMHO. (But again, I do see where you're coming from. The term "uninitialized" leads folks with a C or C++ background to expect total garbage, which just isn't the Go way.)

Answer (score 0):

For structs and other composites, both are same.

```
t1:=&T{}
t2:=new(T)
//Both are same
```

You cannot return the address of un-named variable initialised to zero value of other basic types like int without using `new`. You would need to create a named variable and then take its address.

```
func newInt() *int {            
    return new(int)                 
}
```

```
func newInt() *int {
    // return &int{} --> invalid
    var dummy int
    return &dummy
}
```

Comment: Well for struct type, this is not the case: func newT1() *T1{return &T1{}} compiles and runs well

Comment: That's what my answer says. It works for struct types but not for other basic types like int.

Answer (score 0):

See [ruakh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59807885/1256452).  I want to point out some of the internal implementation details, though.  You should not make use of them in production code, but they help illuminate what really happens behind the scenes, in the Go runtime.

Essentially, a slice is represented by three values.  The `reflect` package exports a type, [`SliceHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader):

> SliceHeader is the runtime representation of a slice. It cannot be used safely or portably and its representation may change in a later release. Moreover, the Data field is not sufficient to guarantee the data it references will not be garbage collected, so programs must keep a separate, correctly typed pointer to the underlying data.
>
> ```
> type SliceHeader struct {
>         Data uintptr
>         Len  int
>         Cap  int
> }
> ```

If we use this to inspect a variable of type `[]T` (for any type `T`), we can see the three parts: the pointer to the underlying array, the length, and the capacity.  Internally, a slice value `v` always has all three of these parts.  There's a general condition that I think *should* hold, and if you don't use `unsafe` to break it, it seems by inspection that it *will* hold (based on limited testing anyway):

- either the `Data` field is not zero (in which case `Len` and `Cap` can but need not be nonzero), or
- the `Data` field is zero (in which case the `Len` and `Cap` should both be zero).

That slice value `v` is `nil` if the `Data` field is zero.

By using the `unsafe` package, we can break it deliberately (and then put it all back—and hopefully nothing goes wrong while we have it broken) and thus inspect the pieces.  When [this code on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mwj-5AB3hMJ) is run (there's a copy below as well), it prints:

```
via &literal: base of array is 0x1e52bc; len is 0; cap is 0.
Go calls this non-nil.

via new: base of array is 0x0; len is 0; cap is 0.
  Go calls this nil even though we clobbered len() and cap()
  Making it non-nil by unsafe hackery, we get [42] (with cap=1).

after setting *p1=nil: base of array is 0x0; len is 0; cap is 0.
  Go calls this nil even though we clobbered len() and cap()
  Making it non-nil by unsafe hackery, we get [42] (with cap=1).
```

The code itself is a bit long so I have left it to the end (or use the above link to the Playground).  But it shows that the actual `p == nil` test in the source compiles to just an inspection of the `Data` field.

When you do:

```
p2 := new([]int)
```

the `new` function actually allocates only the slice *header*.  It sets all three parts to zero and returns the pointer to the resulting header.  So `*p2` has three zero fields in it, which makes it a correct `nil` value.

On the other hand, when you do:

```
p1 := &[]int{}
```

the Go compiler builds an empty array (of size zero, holding zero ints) and then builds a slice header: the pointer part points to the empty array, and the length and capacity are set to zero.  Then `p1` points to this header, with the non-nil `Data` field.  A later assignment, `*p1 = nil`, writes zeros into all three fields.

**Let me repeat this with boldface: these are not promised by the language specification, they're just the actual implementation in action.**

Maps work very similarly.  A map variable is actually a pointer to a *map header*.  The details of map headers are even less accessible than those of slice headers: there is no `reflect` type for them.  The actual implementation is viewable [here](https://golang.org/src/runtime/map.go) under `type hmap` (note that it is not exported).

What this means is that `m2 := new(map[T1]T2)` really only allocates one *pointer*, and set that pointer itself to nil.  There is no actual map!  The `new` function returns the nil pointer, and `m2` is then `nil`.  Likewise `var m1 map[T1]T2` just sets a simple pointer value in `m1` to `nil`.  But `var m3 map[T1]T2{}` allocates an actual `hmap` structure, fills it in, and makes `m3` point to it.  We can once again [peek behind the curtain on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/li8iD5UhzRK), with code that is not guaranteed to work tomorrow, to see this in effect.

As someone writing Go programs, you don't *need* to know any of this.  But if you have worked with lower-level languages (assembly and C for instance), these explain a lot.  In particular, these explain *why* you cannot insert into a nil map: the *map variable itself* holds a pointer value, and until the *map variable itself* has a non-nil pointer to a (possibly empty) map-header, there is no way to do the insertion.  An insertion could allocate a new map and insert the data, but the *map variable* wouldn't point to the correct `hmap` header object.

(The language authors could have made this work by using a second level of indirection: a map variable could be a pointer pointing to the variable that points to the map header.  Or they could have made map variables always point to a header, and made `new` actually allocate a header, the way `make` does; then there would never be a nil map.  But they didn't do either of these, and we get what we get, which is fine: you just need to know to initialize the map.)

---

Here's the slice inspector.  (Use the playground link to view the map inspector: given that I had to copy `hmap`'s definition out of the runtime, I expect it to be particularly fragile and not worth showing.  The slice header's structure seems far less likely to change over time.)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    p1 := &[]int{}
    p2 := new([]int)
    show("via &literal", *p1)
    show("\nvia new", *p2)
    *p1 = nil
    show("\nafter setting *p1=nil", *p1)
}

// This demonstrates that given a slice (p), the test
//    if p == nil
// is really a test on p.Data.  If it's zero (nil),
// the slice as a whole is nil.  If it's nonzero, the
// slice as a whole is non-nil.
func show(what string, p []int) {
    pp := unsafe.Pointer(&p)
    sh := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(pp)
    fmt.Printf("%s: base of array is %#x; len is %d; cap is %d.\n",
        what, sh.Data, sh.Len, sh.Cap)
    olen, ocap := len(p), cap(p)
    sh.Len, sh.Cap = 1, 1 // evil
    if p == nil {
        fmt.Println("  Go calls this nil even though we clobbered len() and cap()")
        answer := 42
        sh.Data = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&answer))
        fmt.Printf("  Making it non-nil by unsafe hackery, we get %v (with cap=%d).\n",
            p, cap(p))
        sh.Data = 0 // restore nil-ness
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Go calls this non-nil.")
    }
    sh.Len, sh.Cap = olen, ocap // undo evil
}
```